# import data from excel to exist access database that replace if data is exist otherwise new row will create

Tags: excel, ms-access

Here is Excel file:

[image]

I created a database name "Activities_open_projects_19_OCT_17_BL_Fin_AA". table name is "Activities open projects (BL Fi".  Its "Activity ID" column is unique and not allow non duplicate value. I imported a excel file successfully . but  now I want to import same type of file and need to replace data if data is exist otherwise new row will create according to "Activity ID".

please share a link or help how to solve it.

Here is access file:

[image]

Comment: It's not a one-step process. Bring the file in as a new table, then build two queries: one to UPDATE existing records in the first table, and one to INSERT records into it.

Comment: have any link to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no direct solution for what you want to do. it will be a 4 step process.

Step 1 : import new excel data in temporary table.

Step 2 : create update query to update existing data based on your unique ID.

Step 3 : create insert query to insert new records to your main table.

Step 4 : delete temporary table if not required.

if you had shared sample excel data, it would have been easy to provide you detail solution.

Comment: have any link to do this

Comment: It's not a simple thing requiring a few button clicks. You need to take the time to learn how to build the queries and integrate them into your workflow. It's not a difficult process, but at the same time it isn't the sort of thing that anyone on here will spell out for you step by step. Try it out and ask questions about specific problems that you run into.